# Creating shared library in C, problems with sqlite3

Tags: c, sqlite, shared-libraries, swi-prolog

I am trying for the first time to create a shared library for using it with SWI-Prolog foreign function interface, but I am not able to get sqlite3 properly linked. I actually do this:

```
gcc -c -fpic task_resources.prolog.c -I/usr/lib/swi-prolog/include/ -lsqlite3
gcc -shared -o task_resources.so task_resources.prolog.o
cp /home/markmb/task_resources.so /usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/amd64/task_resources
```

Then I have a dummy prolog file:

```
dbg_task_resources :- 
   use_foreign_library(foreign(task_resources)),
   getTaskState("id01",Result),
   write(Result).
```

At the prolog intepreter, I call the file and the functor:

```
[prueba].
dbg_task_resources.
```

And I get the result:

```
prolog: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/amd64/task_resources: undefined symbol: sqlite3_open
```

How should I link sqlite3, then?

Comment: Is the location of libsqlite3.so in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH or in one of the system's standard library search paths ?

Comment: I'd bet you just need to add `-lsqlite3` to your second call to GCC. It's not needed in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Collin said, I needed -sqlite3 in the second gcc statement:

```
gcc -shared -o task_resources.so task_resources.prolog.o -lsqlite3
```

Sorry for the easy question, then, but this is a specific question and I couldn't find solution looking at Google

Thank you again Collin